# SpringBoot : RestAPI display the unique record

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Table :
[this is table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk8hj.png)

**Requirement :**

Using RestAPI call populate unique cateID, categoryName , but I am getting the whole record.

**Table**

[Table Data which I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNNe.png)

**Code Description :**

**Repository :**

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<xCategory,Integer>
{
    // @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.catID,a.categoryName FROM  ccCategory a order by categoryName asc")
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.catID, a.categoryName FROM xCategory a order by categoryName asc")
    List<ccCategory> getCategoryName();
}
```

**Rest Controller:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
public class HomeResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeResource.class);

    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;



@GetMapping("/getAllCategory")
    public List<ccCategory> getAllCategory() {
        // public List<String> getAllCategory() {
        System.out.println("***** Call : API getAllCategory() ******");

        List<ccCategory> cCategory = categoryRepository.findAll();
        return cCategory;
    }
```

**Angular Code :**

```
<label class="control-label">Category: </label>
                <select  [(ngModel)]="listAllCategory" name="xxcategory" class="form-control" required>
                    <option *ngFor="let xxcategory of listAllCategory" [value]="xxcategory.catID">
                        {{xxcategory.categoryName}}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

**Problem :** 
Drop Down populating all the  table value but I want only the UNIQUE value like only one time catID , categoryName.

Comment: API populate unique data right ?

Comment: Start getting the Unique Data .... Only change in Repository

Comment: ABHI you are right but My data is not populating in JSON format....any specific reason it coming as [[1,"A"],[2,"V"]

Comment: Did you check any error in RestAPI App ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a variable to keep the selected element in your `select` and then change your `[(ngModel)]="listAllCategory"` with `[(ngModel)]="selectedCategory"`

Comment: Angular side I am getting the data that is not a issue .